# Appcelerator Titanium click event coordinates out of bounds on (some) Android

Tags: android, click, titanium, appcelerator

I have a simple view that captures clicks and evaluates them on a complex image.  On some phones (Samsung S3 Mini with Android 4.1.2) the code works fine, on others (HTC One X with Android 4.1.1) it doesn't.  The problem appears to be click coordinates are out of bounds.

In my view, I have an object: viewCanvas with a width of 1250 and a height of 290.  But when I click the lower right hand corner (for example) my event.x = 1762.20214 and event.y = 531.23968

Why??  Shouldn't x/y in the event be bound by the dimensions of the view object?  I have checked event.source.id and it is the correct object: viewObject, and event.source.rect shows the correct width and height.  I'm stumped, has anyone seen this before?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was uncovered to be a miss-representation of screen dimensions, one in DP (density independent pixels) and the other in just pixels.  The view was reporting in android pixels but the event was reporting in DP since we had that selected in the tiapp.xml as our default units.  See the details here:

http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/178626/click-event-coordinates-out-of-range-on-some-android-platforms

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In Titanium the touch coordinates should always be the coordinates of the view which is touched. This is also manifested in the [documentation](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/guide/Event_Handling) (`x and y which describe the x/y coordinates of the event in the view's coordinates`). But especially on Android this does not work as suggested. Especially webViews and imageViews are very likely to swallow the touch events without properly processing them (the listeners are not always triggered). Another thing I recognized while working with Titanium was the behaviour you are describing: Some coordinates seem to be out of bounds. Unfortunately I was neither able to reproduce this properly (i.e. constantly) nor to find out what caused this behaviour.

Your case supports the theory that Titanium mixes up touch events. Even if the touch event was somehow bubbled to the parent view an event.x = 1762 seems to be impossible on a 1280x720 display.

Finally I hope that this explanation was somehow useful for you although I am not able to solve your problems.